# Using AdMob with multiple listeners

Tags: java, android, admob

How do I load multiple rewarded videos `onCreate()` and then call them to show the ad at whatever time, while using the correct listener?

I have 5 different rewarded video "zones" so for example viewing button1 ads would give tokens, button2 ad gives coins, button3 ad let's you skip something etc etc. If you click button1 it should show the ad then do whatever I need, and so on.

AdMob is setup with different Ad Units for each of those zones, so how do I:

- Load the ad unit when app starts?
- Have it using its own listener so I can perform the appropriate action?

You can only load one ad. The above will only load the last one:

```
mAd.loadAd("AD_UNIT_1", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
mAd.loadAd("AD_UNIT_2", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
mAd.loadAd("AD_UNIT_3", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

You can only have one listener for that `mAd` object.

So how am I supposed to go about doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In on create load individual add listeners .

```
adView1.loadAd(adRequest);
adView2.loadAd(adRequest);
adView3.loadAd(adRequest);
```